# Javascript - mistaking function calls

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps

I want a function which does some calculations to be called each time the route is edited.
The *route_has_been_edited* event is emitted only by an existing route (pitily).
I connect the event of deselecting `routeEditor` control (which means the route has just been created) to a function call.
This nameless function creates a connection between `routeupdate` event in the freshly made `route` and the calculating function.
Here is my *noob* attempt to code it

```
routeEditor.events.add ('deselect', function (e) {
    var route = e.get('target').getRoute();
    alert ('Route length - ' + route.getLength());
    // notice me, senpai
    route.Editor.events.add ('routeupdate', recalc(polygon, route));
    recalc (polygon, route);
    alert("Watashi o mushi shinaide kudasaaai (>_<)");
});
```

I didn't check if I have done the second event connection right, but even despite that, **why** does the first alert work, and second does not?

Comment: Is the console showing any errors?

Comment: @mwilson that is the strangest part. Not even a warning

Comment: Can you put together a JSFiddle of the complete code or reproduction of the issue?

Comment: Does the function `recalc()` return a function? Because in your `routeUpdate` event, you're **calling** `recalc`, instead of passing it.

Comment: @mwilson is a github link satisfactory? https://github.com/mekkanizer/taxi-dispatcher/blob/master/test/test.js

Comment: In fact, I'm certain it does not, looking at it again. You probably want to call `recalc(polygon, route)` inside the callback. Such as `events.add('routeupdate', function () { recalc(polygon, route) })`

Comment: @azium is the solution to write `recalc`? Without arguments?

Comment: Also it looks like you're adding the `routeupdate` event on EVERY `deselect` event fire.. are you sure you don't want to hookup that event handler just one time?

Comment: @azium whooops I guess you're right. Of course, I want to hook it only once. And pitily, neither deleting arguments nor using your code helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo that's causing JS to error out (even though you're not seeing it, maybe errors are off?).

Change:

`route.Editor.events...`

To:

`routeEditor.events...`

If that's not a typo, try commenting out the line with `route.Editor` and confirm that both alerts fire. It could be that `recalc` is also causing a JS crash.

Comment: The names seem to be confusing. Let me tell you the difference between `routeEditor` and `route.Editor`. The first one is a [control](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.RouteEditor-docpage/), and the second one is an [event emitter](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/router.Editor-docpage/#events-summary).

Comment: However, my friend suggested just erasing `.Editor`, and the second alert started working, now I have to figure out if the event hook *does* work with those edits

Comment: The difference is that `routeEditor` is in the closure where as `route` is returned from the `getRoute()` method which might not be working as you expect. If the object is following javascript conventions the property on `route` should be should be `route.editor` not `route.Editor`. If my above suggestion works you should accept this answer to clear it from the unanswered queue.

Comment: ok, i finally figured everything. solution is three things: * change `route.Editor.events` to simply `route.events`; * add `function () { ` before the second argument of second `events.add`; * remove `return function () {` from the `recalc` method declaration line